Etymology of “real numbers"
I would like to know why the real numbers are called “the real numbers.” I would also like to know the meaning of “real” in the phrase “real number.”
Further questions and clarifications:

I’d like to know both why the phrase is used now and why it was initially introduced (should these two differ), though I’m most interested in the latter question.
When did the phrase “real numbers” come to denote the reals? In what language did this terminology first appear? Who first used it? Did it quickly see widespread acceptance, or was there pushback?
The most likely explanation, to my ears, is that “real” is meant to mark a contrast with “imaginary”: real numbers can be given physical interpretations (by representing physical magnitudes such as charge, force, etc.; functions on reals could represent the dynamics of physical systems) whereas imaginary numbers cannot, hence the terminology. But this explanation implies that the phrase “real numbers” only came to denote real numbers after the introduction of imaginary numbers. Perhaps the historical evidence suggests otherwise? This explanation also suggests that there are no physical interpretations of imaginary numbers—this sounds doubtful to me, though perhaps it would have seemed obvious back when the terms were introduced.
Note that many other languages use a synonym of “real” to denote the real numbers (e.g. French: “nombre réel," German: “reelle Zahl," Chinese: “实数”).

The rationale for “rational number” is pretty clear (though I don’t actually know the history). “Natural number” is less transparent. Any historical/etymological insights on that one welcome too.

Possibly better suited for https://hsm.stackexchange.com/. Also this website: https://jeff560.tripod.com/r.html (Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics) claims that "real number" was introduced by Descartes, in French of course. An the entry under "imaginary" (https://jeff560.tripod.com/i.html) has much more info.

Meta: I don't understand the downvote(s) on this question. The origin of the term “real number” is a perfectly good and sensible question on the history of mathematics / mathematical terminology, and while it may indeed be more appropriate for HSM StackExchange (which could be a reason to close it here), downvoting should be used in lieu of voting to close.

Almost certainly, "real" numbers were named after the word "imaginary" was used to describe the square roots of negative real numbers, in order to distinguish reals from imaginaries.

Before the distinction imaginary/real numbers arose, real numbers were referred to by Stevin as "continuous" numbers, in distinction with rationals (source)

What you call "synonym" would rather be "literal translation". Also note that a priori the word was not translated from English, but to English.

@YCor, getting even more off topic, but the technical term is calque.

@PeterTaylor, calque seems to be used when a word is transmogrified into a different language by formal transfer of word roots (rather than meaning), as for example when Bachet rendered Diophantus' parisotes as adaequo (hence Fermat's adequality).  But here arguably the transmogrification is based on meaning.

@PeterTaylor I indeed meant "literal translation" rather than calque (well, the Chinese word is certainly not a calque; the German might be one).

I am glad that all of the "Close" votes have now expired. This is certainly a historical Question whose Answer the general mathematician ought to know.

I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to HSM

I believe the distinction between real and imaginary number was introduced first by Descartes; e.g.,

Au reste, tant les vraies racines que les fausses ne sont pas toujours réelles, mais quelquefois seulement imaginaires

(see here, page 47).
The idea of arbitrary number (rational or otherwise) represented by an unending decimal was popularized even earlier by Stevin but I am not aware of him referring to such numbers as "real".  Some details on Stevin and real numbers can be found in

Katz, K.; Katz, M. "Stevin numbers and reality." Foundations of Science 17 (2012), no. 2, 109-123. https://doi.org/10.1007/s10699-011-9228-9 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.3688 and https://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2935194

Cauchy was, of course, aware of this approach to the real numbers.  Therefore in my view the widespread idea that his proofs of such results as the intermediate value theorem are somehow incomplete or lacking, is exaggerated.

Only the first sentence of this answer has anything to do with the question asked (and this fact was also mentioned in the first comment, with references).

The fact that real numbers were known before Descartes (though not under that name) is significant.

For anyone else on here as ignorant of French as I am, here is the translation that google gave me: "Moreover, both the true roots and the false ones are not always real, but sometimes only imaginary."

@WillBrian, as explained there on page 41, "false" means "negative".

@MikhailKatz: Thanks Mikhail. I was wondering what the "false ones" might mean. (As I mentioned in my comment, I do not speak French.)

@WillBrian, the negatives were not considered "genuine numbers" until quite late; I believe in Cauchy one still finds discussions of signs that make it appear that the negatives are "false" somehow :-)

An excellent explanation is given in the short paper of

N. J. Wildberger, Real fish, real numbers, real jobs, The Mathematical Intelligencer 21 (1999) pp 4–7. https://doi.org/10.1007/BF03024838 (ResearchGate)

It was published in the Math Intelligencer, which is available by subscription only, but here is a youtube movie where the author just reads this paper:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VUdFdlQNfpg
[[Added by David Roberts: This article comes with a disclaimer

The Opinion  column  offers
mathematicians  the opportunity  to
write about  any issue of interest  to
the international  mathematical
community.  Disagreement  and
controversy  are welcome.  The views
and opinions  expressed  here,  however,
are exclusively  those  of the author,
and neither  the publisher  nor the
editor-in-chief  endorses  or accepts
responsibility  for them

]]

Any chance you could summarise the main points of the explanation in your Answer?

@Paul Taylor: I cannot summarize it better than he does himself :-)

Wildberger attributes complex numbers to "The Europeans" without any dates.  This is not a very informative way of writing history.

@Michael Katz: He wrote this for mathematicians, not for the "general audience", and mathematicians know who invented complex numbers:-)

The issue here is not complex numbers but real numbers, and he doesn't tell us who invented those.  Your post does not answer the question.

@Mikhail Katz: and my answer is written for mathematicians who have a sense of humor:-)

The summary seems to be "satire" and I've heard better. I gave up after 10 minutes out of 21. I'm glad I didn't pay the subscription. Hardly an Answer to a reasonable Question.

@PaulTaylor, I can send you a pdf of Wildberger's piece (though he certainly does not provide an answer to OP).

@MikhailKatz: no thanks. your Answer is much more to the point.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225795896_Real_fish_real_numbers_real_jobs
